# Require some help deciphering a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match the following two string types:

```
Name(p0, p1,...pN)
```

and:

```
Name()
```

I'm currently using the regular expression:

```
@"[a-z]+\([^()]+\)"
```

I can understand that:

```
[a-z]        = Match any character from a to z
```

I'm not so sure of:

```
[^()]        ?= Match any character between '(' and ')'
```

I believe it belongs to a [group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx) denoted by:

```
\([^()]+\)
```

but again, I am not certain.

Currently the expression will work for:

```
Name(p0, p1,...pN)
```

but I can't get it to match when there are no comma delimited characters between the brackets.  That is:

```
Name()
```

Why does the expression fail for the second one?

EDIT:

From your answers I have ascertained the following (please correct me if wrong):

```
         +            = ONE or more times
         *            = ZERO or more times
         []           = Groups characters to match or ignore
         ^            = Logical NOT

         [a-z]+       = Match a lowercase letter (ONE or more times) 
         \(           = Match the character '('
         [^()]*       = Match anything that's NOT '(' or ')' (ZERO or more times)
         \)           = Match the character ')'
```

Comment: Have you considered reading a basic regular expression intro?

Comment: @phant0m to get this far, I am pretty sure he has read a basic intro. Regex can seem a little cryptic, and the point of this forum is to be able to ask questions about things like this.

Comment: From the sudden influx of answers I am able to get a lot further.  Thank you to all those who have posted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[a-z]+       = Match any character from a to z, 1 or more times
\(           = Match "(" literally
[^()]+       = Match anything that's NOT "(" or ")", 1 or more times
\)           = Match ")" literally
```

Like Billy Moon says, use * instead of + in the third "part" to match "non-parentheses inside parentheses" 0 or more times, rather than 1 or more times.

The parentheses don't constitute a group - they're escaped with "\".

Answer (score 4):

Here is an explanation of your expression:

```
[a-z]+\([^()]+\)
  ^  ^ ^  ^  ^ ^
  |  | |  |  | |
  |  | |  |  | +-- The closing parenthesis
  |  | |  |  +---- Repeated one or more time
  |  | |  +------- Any character other than '(' or ')'
  |  | +---------- The opening parenthesis
  |  +------------ Repeated one or more time
  +--------------- A lowercase letter
```

The only part that you got wrong was the `[^()]` sub-expression: the `^` character at the beginning alters its meaning to be "exclusive of" rather than "inclusive of" the rest of the characters of the character class.

If you would like to match an empty pair of parentheses, replace the last `+` with `*` to change the meaning from "one or more" to "any number, inclusive of zero".

Comment: most legible regex explanation i've seen

Answer (score 3):

Use `*` instead of `+` near the end...

```
@"[a-z]+\([^()]*\)"
```

The `[^()]+` part means negatively match a class (`[^...]`), as in not a bracket (`()`) one or more times (`+`). But you want it to be zero or more times (`*`) so that it matches even when there are no elements.

Comment: You might want to add an *explanation* that is asked for in the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not so sure of: [^()]

That is a character class meaning "something that is not a ( or a )"
which is a little greedy. (Really depends on your requirements, are line breaks allowed etc.)

> I believe it belongs to a group denoted by: ()

It would be a group, if it were not escaped by backslashes. Like this, it tells the regex to look for braces.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
@"[A-Za-z]+\(([\w,. ])*\)"
```

If the ... in your original example is just a shortened version for this question, and the actual data contains not dots, you may remove the dot from the character class as well.

Comment: +1 for the comment about the possible over-greediness of `[^()]` - was about to add the same to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Expresso Regular Expression Tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

I always use it when dealing with complex expressions.